# Vim output of external command

Tags: vim

Can anyone explain the various ways of doing external command like `:!` `:%!` and how to put them at the end of a file? I understand that `:X` puts them after line X, but `:G` does not appear to put them at the end of the file.

I guess I could always run the command and append it to the file from the command line `command >> %` but would this immediately show up in vim? Is there a better way?

I always reading that Vim can be used as a hex editor but if you don't edit in binary it may break the file...why?

Comment: If you have multiple questions to ask, ask multiple questions.

Answer (score 2):

`[count]G` is a normal mode command used to move he cursor to line `[count]`, defaulting to the last line if no `[count]` is given. You can't use it as a range for an Ex command.

In a range, the shortcut for "last line" is `$`.

The difference between `:!command` and `:{range}!command` is that the former executes `command` in a subshell without passing anything to the command via `stdin` while the latter passes the `{range}` to `command` via `stdin` and replaces it with the output of `command`. It is called a *filter* and you can read all about it in `:help filter`.

Since you don't seem to want to filter the content of your buffer, the right pattern for simply reading the output of `command` would be `:!command`.

`:read` is the right command to use if you want to insert the output of an external command in the current buffer.

Use this command to insert the output of external command `command` below the current line:

```
:r!command
```

Use this command to insert the output of external command `command` below line 15:

```
:15r!command
```

Use this command to insert the output of external command `command` below the next "foo":

```
:/foo/r!command
```

Use this command to append the output of external command `command` to the current buffer:

```
:$r!command
```

Use this one to *prepend* the output of external command `command` to the current buffer:

```
:0r!command
```

See `:help :read!` and `:help range`.